# Problem in use firebase-messaging with androidX

Tags: android, firebase, gradle

I try to use `firebase-messaging` and `androidX`. for this, I add this library like this to project `gradle` file.

```
dependencies {
//support library
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0-rc02'
implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0-rc02'
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.0-rc02'
implementation 'androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0-rc02'
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.0-rc02'
implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.0.0-rc02'
implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
...
implementation ('com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.3.1'){
    }
}
```

I face this error :

Program type already present: `android.support.v4.media.MediaBrowserCompat$MediaBrowserImplApi21$1 Message{kind=ERROR, text=Program type already present: android.support.v4.media.MediaBrowserCompat$MediaBrowserImplApi21$1, sources=[Unknown source file], tool name=Optional.of(D8)}`

I change `gradle` file like this:

```
dependencies {
    //support library
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0-rc02'
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0-rc02'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.0-rc02'
    implementation 'androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0-rc02'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.0-rc02'
    implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.0.0-rc02'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    ...
  implementation ('com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.3.1'){
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module:'support-v4'
    }
 }
```

Now application compile successfully but crashes on run with this error:

```
09-18 14:51:46.372 17956-17956/ir.rotbeshoo E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: ir.rotbeshoo, PID: 17956
    java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Landroid/support/v4/util/ArrayMap;
        at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.<clinit>(com.google.firebase:firebase-common@@16.0.1:136)
        at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.initializeApp(com.google.firebase:firebase-common@@16.0.1:274)
        at com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider.onCreate(com.google.firebase:firebase-common@@16.0.1:37)
        at android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo(ContentProvider.java:1751)
        at android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo(ContentProvider.java:1726)
        at com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider.attachInfo(com.google.firebase:firebase-common@@16.0.1:31)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:6203)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:5721)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:5639)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap2(ActivityThread.java)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1637)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:156)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6523)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:942)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:832)
     Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "android.support.v4.util.ArrayMap" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/ir.rotbeshoo-1/base.apk", zip file "/data/app/ir.rotbeshoo-1/split_lib_dependencies_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/ir.rotbeshoo-1/split_lib_slice_0_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/ir.rotbeshoo-1/split_lib_slice_1_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/ir.rotbeshoo-1/split_lib_slice_2_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/ir.rotbeshoo-1/split_lib_slice_3_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/ir.rotbeshoo-1/split_lib_slice_4_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/ir.rotbeshoo-1/split_lib_slice_5_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/ir.rotbeshoo-1/split_lib_slice_6_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/ir.rotbeshoo-1/split_lib_slice_7_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/ir.rotbeshoo-1/split_lib_slice_8_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/ir.rotbeshoo-1/split_lib_slice_9_apk.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/ir.rotbeshoo-1/lib/arm64, /system/lib64, /vendor/lib64, /system/vendor/lib64, /product/lib64]]
        at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:380)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312
```

Comment: Can you add your compileSdkVersion?

Comment: @G.Ciardini . compileSdkVersion 28

Comment: Have you tried to clean and rebuild the project?

Comment: Did you find any solution?

Comment: @SumitSaurabh In my case with update android studio problem solved.